Stepper motor stutters when connected to a TB6612 stepper motor driver and a Raspberry Pi
I've wired a stepper motor to a TB6612 stepper motor driver which is in turn connected to a Raspberry Pi. The wiring is as follows.
VM ---> +12V power supply (the adapter used for this can supply up to 1.5A)
GND ---> GND
VCC ---> 5V in Raspberry Pi
GND ---> GND
PWMB ---> 5V in Raspberry Pi
BIN2 ---> D21
BIN1 ---> D20
AIN1 ---> D19
AIN2 ---> D26
PWMA ---> 5V in Raspberry Pi
MOTORA ---> stepper coil (red and yellow stepper wires)
MOTORB ---> stepper coil (green and grey stepper wires)
A diagram is given below.

I've been using the code from adafruit (original code). It has been edited to try a number of different delays to see whether there is any change to the rotation. The edited code is given below:
import time
import board
import digitalio
from adafruit_motor import stepper

#DELAY = 0.0005
DELAY = [0.01,0.001225,0.0008,0.0005,0.00009]
STEPS = 10000

#To use with a Raspberry Pi:
coils = (
    digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D19),  # A1
    digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D26),  # A2
    digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D20),  # B1
    digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D21),  # B2
)

for coil in coils:
    coil.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

motor = stepper.StepperMotor(coils[0], coils[1], coils[2], coils[3], microsteps=None)

for x in DELAY:
    print(x)

    print("C")
    for step in range(STEPS):
        motor.onestep(style=stepper.DOUBLE)
        time.sleep(x)

    print("D")
    for step in range(STEPS):
        motor.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.DOUBLE)
        time.sleep(x)

The specifications for the motor are as follows (it is used as part of a peristaltic pump):

Step angle: 1.8 degrees​
Holding torque: 4.2 kg·cm​
Current: 1.3 A​
Voltage: 12 V​
Resistance: 45 Ω​
Inductance: 2.5 mH​
Shaft diameter: 5 mm​
Shaft length: 12 mm

Problem is that the motor doesn't rotate. It just vibrates a bit. On top of that, the driver module's IC heats up a lot and on two occasions, they simply broke.
I've checked all the wiring, looked and conductivity, used different motors, used a different breadboard, and even used new driver modules, but I keep getting the same issue. Is my problem with the code? Or is there any other place I need to look at?

What kind of stepper motor ?

@Antonio51, it should be a bipolar stepper motor. I have uploaded a pic of the motor itself.

How much peak current does your stepper motor consume? Can you measure your 12 V with an oscilloscope during the "not rotating but vibrating" part? Does it collapse? How does A, A!, B and B! look?

@winny I don't have an oscilloscope with me, can I get a good enough idea of the peak current using a multimeter?




On top of that, the driver module's IC heats up a lot and on two occasions, they simply broke.On top of that, the driver module's IC heats up a lot and on two occasions, they simply broke.<<< Lower than the power voltage supply ... until ~ 2.5 V.




No, but you can make a good enough oscilloscope out of an Arduino if you want. Also, put a honker of a capacitor on your 12 V rail close to the driver and see if the situation improves.

@winny how big a capacitor would you recommend?

Make a stack of the biggest MLCCs you have. Several 10 uF?

So, I think I figured out why the motor stutters and the IC gets damaged after looking inquiring in a separate forum.
The specifications for this motor mentioned that the winding resistance is around 45Ω, but when I checked the resistance on each of the coils, it was around 2Ω. This means that a very high current is drawn and it will damage the chip.
12V/2Ω = 6A (the TB6612 can handle 3.2A at most)
It would be a good idea to try using a different module like the DRV8833, or the A4988. What I am not sure about is that the TB6612 was used with this same motor in a different project I know of and it is working fine.​
